# Calling index function of a controller in another function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a problem on create a function that calling a function (index function). For ease of understanding let me explain it:

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        echo 'This is index function';
    }

    public function calling_index(){
        // doing what's inside the index() function
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->index()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be an issue in using

```
$this->index()
```

as the controller is simply a class

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much